Conditional Probability in Selection of Nuts from Different Weight Distributions
I'm struggling with solving a problem involving conditional probability. Here's the problem:
There are three species of nuts: those from the canton of St. Gallen (Switzerland), whose weight in grams is a random variable with the following probability density function:
$$
f_A(x) = 
\begin{cases}
c & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq 9 \\
kx^2 & \text{if } 10 \leq x \leq 15 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where $k$ and $c$ are unknown positive constants. It is known that exactly 90% of nuts from this species weigh less than 12 grams.
The second species comes from Bavaria (Germany), with a weight distribution that is uniform, having a minimum of 5 grams and a median of 9 grams.
Lastly, we have nuts from Gmunden (Austria), with a weight distribution that follows a normal distribution with an unknown mean and a standard deviation of 3 grams. It is known that the probability of a Gmunden nut weighing more than 11 grams is 0.3.
Now, let's say we combine 30 nuts from St. Gallen, 20 from Bavaria, and 15 from Gmunden in a box. If we randomly pick a nut and find that it weighs more than 10 grams, which of the three types of nuts would be the most probable?
Let's denote the event of picking a nut from St. Gallen as $A$, from Bavaria as $B$, and from Gmunden as $G$. We want to find $P(A|X>10)$, $P(B|X>10)$, and $P(G|X>10)$, where $X$ represents the weight of the selected nut.
I'd appreciate any guidance on how to approach the conditional probability aspect of this problem, including calculating $P(X>10)$ and $P(X>10|B)$, and using Bayes' theorem to find $P(A|X>10)$, $P(B|X>10)$, and $P(G|X>10)$.

I will just find the probability of picking a nut from Bavaria (given its weight is >10) since you can then do the others. You must use Bayes theorem
$$ P(B|X>10) = \frac{P(X>10|B)P(B)}{P(X>10)},$$
so lets calculate each term on the RHS above.

$P(X>10|B):$ We want to calculate the probability that the weight of the nut is greater than 10 given that the nut was taken from Bavaria. Well if the nut is from Bavaria then its weight is a uniform r.v with min $5$ and max $13$. So $P(X>10|B)=\frac{13-10}{13-5}.$
$P(X>10):$ note (people call this the law of total probability) $P(X>10)= P(X>10 \cap A) + P(X>10 \cap B)+ P(X>10 \cap G)$ which can be calculted as $\frac{30}{65}P(``\text{of a nut from  St. Gallen weighing $> 10$}") + \frac{20}{65}P(``\text{of a nut from Bavaria weighing $> 10$}") + \frac{15}{65} P(``\text{of a nut from Gmunden weighing $> 10$}")$
$P(B):$ This is just $20/65$.

